# Filter by Date Range not working django

Tags: django, date, filter, range

My model is:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My views is:

```
def filter_range(request):
    results = Report.objects.filter(created__range=['2012/01/09 00:00','2012/01/11 23:59'])
    return render_to_response("log/filter.html", {'results':results})
```

It gives the error:

```
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    [u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']
```

What could be wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you read the error message?

`2012/01/09` is not in the formt `YYYY-MM-DD`

(slashes aren't dashes)